# Azure Append Blobs Slow Read Performance

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have observed that reading from Azure Append Blob is very slow when a blob is appended to a few thousand times or more. Writing/appending is fast, but reading a typical log blob with a few thousand appends each of size a few KB, for total size of a few MB takes more than a minute! Reading standard blog or page blob of similar size takes milliseconds. Is there some way to speed up reading from append blob, i.e. by flattening internal structure?

So far it looks like that it may be best to periodically "archive" / convert append blobs to block blobs, and then process them. Any suggestion?

If not, what would be recommended alternative storage for logs?
Azure table can be used, but it would take many more reads, even when bulk operations are used.

Answer (score 2):

This is because many small appends will cause the blob to become heavily fragmented, trading fast writes for slow reads.

Currently your best option is, like you wrote, to periodically copy the append blob into a block blob and read from that instead.

However, the Azure storage team have plans (since june 2018) to add a [de-fragmentation feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/17678413-auto-defragment-append-blobs). With that in place we may finally be able to get fast reads for small appends too.

Answer (score 1):

I did switch to Azure Tables and read performance there is reasonable, about 1 second for 1.5K items, read in bulk mode. Still, reading a block or page blob with same content is in milliseconds, much faster. It would be quite effective if there was a way to append to a page blob. That can be done manually, so maybe Append (or some other type of) Blob can automate that in some future version. Append Blobs are quite complex inside [Deep dive in Append Blob](http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.com/2015/08/deep-dive-in-append-blob-new-type-of.html), that is likely reason for slow read.

Answer (score -1):

Please pay attention that append Blobs are made up of blocks. A single append blob could contain up to 50,000 blocks of up to 4MB each. if you append the new content to the existed file, it will caused the slow performance of the file. We could find out the commit number like the following screenshot:
[image]

It is not a good idea to append new content to the file existed in Append blob. Append blob should be used when we need to append content to a blob and we don't care about the order. If you want to use append to log some application information, we can write the new log information to new file and save to Azure append blob. Azure table is also a good service for us to log application information. If we want to find out the log information, we can use [Microsoft Azure Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/).

Comment: Thank you for clarifications, Jambor. Still, it is not clear what is the main use-case for Append Blobs if they are not practical for logs. I did switch to Azure Tables and read performance there is reasonable, about 1 second for 1.5K items, read in bulk mode. Still, a blob or page

Comment: It is ideally suited for storing logging or telemetry data via Append blob, if you want a good performance, I would suggest you create the append blob file per hours or per day. So that we can avoid too large commit blocks in every Append blob file.

Comment: This answer and comment are confusing. On one hand it says that AppendBlobs are not good for appending but on the other it says they are good for appending telemetry and log data. Is the answerer suggesting it is good for appending but only up to a certain size?

Comment: Looks like a copy of [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/83d83158-87e3-4d09-b818-753876f7a536/poor-performance-of-azure-storage-append-blobs?forum=windowsazuredata) (same author) but with more details. Especially that it is best suited where each append is close to the 4MB limit.